# Python - missing imports GUI

Tags: python, import, python-import

Im new in python and I need to work with the following imports but i´ve been having a hard time making them work. I already did the whole pip install on each one of them but they still show as "missing import" on visualCode - is there a way to solve this issue so far im stuck? i have tried deleting them and the installing them once again and the issue still shows - any ideas what might be happening? im using python 3

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
```

Comment: Have you tried the following:

 1. Open the Command Palette by pressing
    Ctrl+Shift+P on your keyboard.
 2. In the Command Palette, select Python: Clear Cache and Reload

Answer (score 0):

First, check your python version.

```
$python --version
```

And if the version is 3.x, you must use the command `pip3 install` in order to get a new package. Because a sole pip is only to apply the python version 2.x. (FYI. although pip can work out in the python 3.x, it's not stable. so, I recommend that you should use the command `pip3` in the 3.x version.)

In summary, if you installed it through `pip install PyQt5`, in the python system, it behave differently. So, you can solve it by following the code.

```
$pip3 install PyQt5 # not pip install, but pip3 install
```